# How can I get a diff of all edits made by a particular author since a particular date in Perforce?

Tags: diff, perforce

In Perforce, I'm trying to find out what edits were made to the code for a particular long-running task. I know that all the changes were made by the same author, and that he was almost invariably working on this particular task.

Given that, I'm trying to find a way to do a diff of all the edits he has made to the code since a particular date. How would I go about it please?

(An alternative might be a way to get a unified diff of all the changes made in a number of specified changelists - I could then sit down and specify all the changelists manually and get a sensible result at the end of it.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something along the lines of this ought to do it:

```
p4 changes -u bruno | awk '{print $2}' | xargs p4 describe
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm on Windows unfortunately, but I can probably find some `awk` and `xargs` equivalents to try it out.